# Android add domain and ip to hosts file programmatically

Tags: android, react-native, hosts, hosts-file

I want to set temporary domain and ip to hosts file. which only activate when the app is running. i want to make app work like [Hosts go](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dns.hosts.server.change&hl=en&gl=US) which works well on not rooted too.

what i'm trying to do is the server is running on Lan computer. so when app load that domain load it from Lan server.
i tried google but all i can find is DnsResolver. can anyone guide me please?

Thanks!